# Gallery of images is not even

Tags: css, wordpress, cpanel

Currently, i've been given a website made in wordpress and i'm supposed to add some content and tweak a few things for it to be finally put online.

Now, my current problem is that when displaying the gallerie of images, not all sheets show images in an orderly form.

Here is an example of what i'm talking about:

[This is how it's supposed to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad2fO.png)

[This is the mistake that keeps happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbLsQ.png)

What gives? What's going on the website that doesn't allow more images? Is it an space thing or what? As of right now i can only modify content through cpanel so a solution in wordpress doesn't help me too much i guess.

I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to find out what's wrong is by taking a look at the source code.

Comment: can you post a link to the site or code?

Comment: http://www.expacientessanjuan.com/como-ayudamos/galeria-5/ This is the part where it shows the images in a messy way..

Comment: If you'd like i can post the source code but maybe it's too long for what this forum allows.

Comment: Can you simplify the portion of the source code that applies to the gallery in specific? By simplifying, you make it easier to provide an answer. You may also discover the answer yourself as you distill the code to a minimal example of the error.

Comment: Looks like a problem stemming from the Slick Track code. The `.slick-track` parent element of your list of images has a width set (I assume by Slick Track), but it's calculating the width of the whole `.awrapper`, which also includes your sidebar. Quick fix, I'd just remove the slick track stuff and just have it be a normal 3-column list of images with no JS required.

Comment: I wrote the code of the first good gallerie sheet and also the css style for the whole page. If someone can see a mistake ,please, i'd like some help.                          https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxGpNB/